# How to extend dims of blob in openvino

Tags: c++, deep-learning, neural-network, openvino

Hello from a beginner of OpenVINO. In the [official tutorial](https://docs.openvino.ai/2021.4/openvino_docs_IE_DG_Integrate_with_customer_application_new_API.html#step-5-prepare-input), the optimal way of taking input for a cascade of networks is

```cpp
auto output = infer_request1.GetBlob(output_name);
infer_request2.SetBlob(input_name, output);
```

However, in my case, the output's layout is `CHW` but the next network's input has an `NCHW` layout. So how could I reshape, or extend the dims of `output` effectively? Or is there any better way to feed blob to the next model in my case?

I tried `input_info->setLayout(Layout::CHW);`, which is taken from openvino's `hello_classification` example, but it didn't do the job (I think I misunderstood this function).

Comment: Could you try reshaping the first network using the reshape() method described here? https://docs.openvino.ai/2021.4/classInferenceEngine_1_1CNNNetwork.html#doxid-class-inference-engine-1-1-c-n-n-network
This way the first model could be changed from CHW to NCHW with N == 1. This way it should match the input of the second model and the blobs should automatically become compatible in terms of their shapes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [InferenceEngine::CNNNetwork::reshape](https://docs.openvino.ai/2021.4/openvino_docs_IE_DG_ShapeInference.html#set-a-new-batch-dimension-value-with-the-setbatchsize-method) to set new input shapes for your first model that does not have batch dimension.